# Cobertura Java7 try with resource

Tags: java, maven-cobertura-plugin

i'm using cobertura 2.6 with maven on java 1.7

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but if i use the new try-with-resource feature of java7 it tells me the "non existing catch" block is missing in tests... it marks the closing bracket of the try-block

any ideas what's wrong? or how i can test them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are probably not testing all the cases for your try with resources block.
Any time that you write something like:

```
try(Autocloseable ac = new Autocloseable()) {
   //do something
} catch(Exception e) {
   //Do something with e
}
```

The compiler interprets something like:

```
Autocloseable ac = null;
Exception e = null;
try {
   ac = new Autocloseable();
   //Do something
} catch (Exception e1) {
   e = e1
   //Do something with exception
} finally {
  if(ac != null) {
     try {
       ac.close();
     } catch (Exception e2) {
        throw e == null? e2 : e;
     }
     if(e != null ) throw e; 
  }
}
```

It is not exactly like that, but is the overall idea, so you see how the actual code branches are a lot more than what you thought could be.
I hope this gives you an idea on how to improve your coverage.